# How do you access an index of the highest number in list, but there's a twist. the list is linked to a class. ill leave the code down below

Tags: python, arrays, class

Please note, I'm quite new to python, so please excuse any of my mistakes.

```
class ArrTrain:
def __init__(self, time, capacity, name, availability, total_price):

class Dep_Train:
def __init__(self, time, capacity, name, availability, total_price):

train_1 = ArrTrain(datetime.time(hour=10), 480, "Train 1", True, 50)
train_2 = ArrTrain(datetime.time(hour=12), 480, "Train 2", True, 0)
train_3 = ArrTrain(datetime.time(hour=14), 480, "Train 3", True, 0)
train_4 = ArrTrain(datetime.time(hour=16), 640, "Train 4", True, 0)

d_train_1 = DepTrain(datetime.time(hour=9), 480, True, 'Train 1', 0)
d_train_2 = DepTrain(datetime.time(hour=11), 480, True, 'Train 2', 0)
d_train_3 = DepTrain(datetime.time(hour=13), 480, True, 'Train 3', 0)
d_train_4 = DepTrain(datetime.time(hour=15), 480, True, 'Train 4', 0)

trains = [train_1.total_price, train_2.total_price, train_3.total_price, train_4.total_price, 
d_train_1.total_price,
          d_train_2.total_price, d_train_3.total_price, d_train_4.total_price]
```

The above should be 1 line only.

I want to print the train with the highest price, and if they have the same price, I want to print them both.
N.B I've already  made the class Deptrain and Arrtrain.
I just didn't type the whole thing up to save time and space

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print out the trains, then the list you constructed should be the train instances, not the `train.total_price`.

Here is an example:

```py
trains = [train_1,train_2,.....]

# get the highest price
maxprice = (max(trains,key=lambda x:x.total_price)).total_price

# filter the list to find all trains that has the highest price.
maxprice_trains = list(filter(lambda x:x.total_price==maxprice, trains))

for train in maxprice_trains:
    print(train)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the maximum element from a list you can use the `max()` function. In case of an empty list you will get a `ValueError`.
For your case it should something like this:

```
   all_trains = [train_1,..., train_4, d_train_1,..., d_train_4]
   # extracting the value of maximum total_price
   max_price_train = max(all_train, key=lambda item: item.total_price)
   # storing the maximum price trains
   max_price_trains = [train for train in all_trains 
                       if train.total_price == max_price_train.total_price]
```

For further documentation on max(), you can go through this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/max-min-python/